# Error Reduction of System of OverDetermined Algebraic Equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

I am trying to perform model reduction on a system of algebraic equations by reducing the number of variables in the system. In doing so I am not trying to remove equations from the system, rather I am trying to remove variables from the system and replace it with an already existing variable. For example:

```
a + b + c = 3
a + b + d = 4
a + b + e = 5
```

and replace this with:

```
a + b + c = 3
a + b + d = 4
a + b + d = 5
```

There will not be an exact solution but I want to minimize error. I am working with a much larger set of functions than was given above. What suggested routes could I utilize to minimize the error that occurred in this problem?

I was looking into SPSA where I would model the mean of the sum of solutions - what my estimated guess would give as the mean of the sum of solutions as the objective function and iterately change the parameters such that error is minimized for that however I am not confident this will work or is even a good way to solve this problem.

I should also mention that I will need to normalize the errors. By that, I am needing to accept larger errors such that I can reduce the sigma of the error seen across each of the individual equations. Reducing the sigma is critical.

My goal is to determine how many variables I can remove while maintaining an acceptable error rate with an acceptable sigma seen across all the errors.

Comment: I think this question needs a little more clarification. What kind of error are you looking to minimize? For example, there is the error between the true solution versus computed solution (numerical error). Another example is error caused by imperfect knowledge of constants in linear equations; in other words, the constants are presumed to be distributed according to some distribution and/or have some variance. Given that, usually the answer to the former relies on the _structure_ of the system of equations, so you may need to add information there too.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza I am trying to minimize the total error of all solutions essentially. My main goal is to have a high correlation or low error for any one of the solutions picked from the system of algebraic equations. That is, while maintaining that one solution doesn't have a drastically high error, so I would need to normalize the error somewhat there. 

What type of information are you wondering about the system of equations?